# How do I properly cite the amount of times an article has been cited on Google Scholar?

Tags: citing

I wish to properly cite the amount of times a paper has been cited according to Google Scholar. However, I couldn't find a proper answer to this question.

The paper in question is:

> Blei, David M., Andrew Y. Ng, and Michael I. Jordan. "Latent dirichlet
>   allocation." the Journal of machine Learning research 3 (2003):
>   993-1022.

Hansen, S., McMahon, M., & Prat, A. (2014) note that

> LDA is widely used (...) and has been cited over 8,000 times

But they cite no source! What is the proper source to cite here?

My first thought was something like this:

> LDA is widely used (...) and has been cited over 10,000 since its
>   publication, a search on Google Scholar reveals (Google Scholar,
>   date).

Comment: Hi and welcome, i am not sure if this is really a TeX related question. The question, right now, seems to be more appropriate at academia.sx.

Comment: I am terribly sorry. I tried to add the tag 'academia' and 'scholar' but I couldn't. Is there any way I can 'cross-post' this question? Or do I have to resubmit it? I apologize for this inconvenience.

Comment: No inconvenience at all. I'll flag the question for migration, if some other members of the community agree that is more suited on academmia, it will be moved.

Comment: Can you explain a little more the issue at hand, what you want to achieve, making the question more clear?